# getting a value from a variable in jsp's input type

Tags: java, jsp

In my jsp i have a variable

```
String str = "Get_Name";
```

What can i do to have my variable(str)  directly accessed in the input type shown below? By this I want to see the form auto filled with the the variable I have instead of me filling it.

```
<input id="vendorName" name="vendorName" type="text" class="txtsmall2" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER ALSO CONTAINS SOLUTION FOR PROBLEM DISCUSSED IN COMMENTS.**

Do this.

```
<%
    long val = 2;   //can be anything.
    if(val > 1) {
%>
<input id="vendorName" name="vendorName" type="text" class="txtsmall2" value="<%=str%>"/>
<%
    else {
%>
<input id="vendorName" name="vendorName" type="text" class="txtsmall2" />
<%
    }
%>
```

`<%=str%>` is called as **expression tag**.

Comment: yup did it.. is there also a way to specify condition inside those expression tags. In my case, lets assume it is a long and  i would like to display it only in case when its value is greater than 1.